# How do I make a NODE GRAPH to use with Dijkstra's Shortest Path?

Tags: c++, graph, dijkstra

I am playing around with Dijkstra's Algorithm and have found many sites and code snippets about it and think I would be able to get a grip on it, but I have found no information on how to build the graph itself. Maybe I do not know the correct terms for a google search, but I just cannot find any information on how to build the grpah it self to graph though.

I am making as a learning project, a small c++ Pac-Man game and wish to use this algorithm to control the ghosts that follow pac-man. I have a map (bitmap) and want to place a "node" at each intersection on the maze.

How do I do this? This is the bit I can not understand. How to build the graph itself ?

Is there a visual graph editor maybe? Any advise would be great.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a visual graph editor ?

Comment: not really.. but I guess that would be cool.. I just wish to make a node graph that I can search with the algorithm. I can not seam to find information on how to do this only on how to search and use teh algorithm  on a graph.. but not how to make one myself.

Comment: "Data Structures and Algorithms in Java" by Goodrich & Tamassia is a good reference for such questions.

Comment: correct!This is the Grid I am trying to make... the red cubes would be the nodes and this is a pixle representation of the map, so the vales of 40x40 for each cube is correct so i can use that for distance.. (http://www3.picturepush.com/photo/a/8845071/img/8845071.png)

Comment: Also , it would be more helpful for you to understand graph representations and basics before starting with the whole project.

Comment: I prefer to learn though doing examples. I will play with simpler things and small outputting to console and stuff first.. but FIRST I need to know how to make the graph itself. Even if it only has 5 nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of grids as graphs and search space representations can be shown using graphs:

[image: Picture of how a grid is like a graph]

Block A,B,C,D are nodes of graph and weights between the nodes can represent path distance between nodes.

Comment: I know this is complicated I am using something simpler for testing but as I had this images I just used it.. Anyway.. see this (http://www5.picturepush.com/photo/a/8845303/img/8845303.png) ... so the "graph" for A would look like this... http://pastie.org/4352683 ?

Answer (score 1):

Graphs can be defined programmatically , the common representations explained below.(Note : For djiksta's algorithm , you would also need to store the weights of the various edges).
Say for example the graph has A connected to B (weight = 5), and B connected to C(weight = 1).

1) **Adjacency list** : Used to represent the edges as lists and is used more commonly for sparse graphs. 
It will have A->B(5) and B->C(1). (It can be promatically represented as an array of linked lists, where each node of the linked list stores the outgoing vertex identification and weight)

2) **Adjacency matrix** :
It will have a 2 dimensional matrix defined as:

```
    A B C
A   0 5 0
B   0 0 1
C   0 0 0
```

EDIT : You could find much more detail at [this topcoder tutorial](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=graphsDataStrucs1) series on graphs : section 1 talks about graph representations and section 3 talks about dijksta' algorithm.

Comment: I think I see.. . so in this example you have A connected to B with a "weight" of 5.. and this could for example represent distance? B is connected to C with a weight of 1?

Comment: You should better look at djikstra algorithm and graphs first , but in your case , yes each node(intersection of the maze) would be connected to each of the neighbours and in general all would have weight = 1 as what  I understand from your design.

Comment: for the 10th time.. I am looking at that BUT all the pages just cover the algorithm. I am trying to learn how to make teh map file itself... I have the algorithm working fine.. I can get shortest paths and all that.. form the provided graph that they supplied in the tutorial.. but I want to know how to make my OWN graphs.

Comment: You could look at this topcoder tutorial , which has graph basics and representation : http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=graphsDataStrucs1 , section 3 of the same tutorial series on graphs also talks about dijkstra's algorithm !

Answer (score 0):

It's all abstract. As such, I'll describe how I'm doing graphs in my android game. Ultimately you can define it anyway you want, but here's my implementation.

A little background, the game is a tower defense and the graph represents paths that the enemies walk on as they make their way from a source to a sink. It wouldn't take much for me to write Dijkstra's algo for my model. I have 3 main classes: `Graph`, `Node`, and `Connection`.

The `Graph` is the main object. It holds a list of Nodes and a list of Connections. This class has methods like `addConnection(Node n1, Node n2, int magnitude)` (this is how I actually build the graph), `getAllSinks()`, `getAllSources()`, and `getNeighbors(Node n)` (returns all nodes that share a connection with the parameter node). This is probably where a `findShortestPath(Node start, Node stop)` method would go.

Since it's a game, a `Node` has the X and Y of its location on the screen. A Node also has a `NodeType` which is an enum for Source, Sink, and Normal (and other game related uses like towers). The NodeType is not required for dijkstra.

My `Connection` is a 1 to 1 link from one Node to another Node and it's bi-directional. You could make it directional if you make a distinction between the two Node endpoints, I just don't need to do that in my game. The Connection stores the Weight of the connection. In my case, I weighted my graph as distance from the sources so enemies can always try and take the "heaviest" path to try and make it to a sink, e.g. the end of the path of a tower defense. The weight could be distance or anything you want. This class has methods like `getOtherEndpoint(Node n)`, `getBothEndpoints()`, and `getWeight()`.

All of these classes are my own construction. They don't inherit from anything. You can build them exactly how you want them and tie any information you need to any piece of the graph. This is just my implementation in Java. You could do the same thing in C++ if you want or if you're inspired to write your own then I won't take it badly.